# Mapping keys on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout, x-server

I'd like to change layout (mapping) of [Lenovo ThinkPad keyboard](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74116320@N08/6675568161/lightbox/) (which I hate)
to be like [Acer TravelMate 8000](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/242466894/Laptop_Keyboard_for_Acer_TravelMate_650_660.jpg) (which I love).

[image: Acer TravelMate 8000 keyboard]

That mainly means:

- Swap Fn and left Ctrl
- Tab-left to act like PgUp
- Fn' + Tab-left to act like Home
- Tab-right to act like PgDown
- Fn' + Tab-right to act like End
- PgUp to act like Delete
- Home to act like Insert

I've tried `xev` to see the codes.
I have found this list of symbols: [http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/n800/keyboard/keysymdef.h](http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esean/stuff/n800/keyboard/keysymdef.h)
This is my result:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112 = XF86Back'     # Remap PgUp to TabPrev
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = XF86Forward'  # Remap PgDn to Tabnext
xmodmap -e 'keycode 166 = Prior Home XF86Back'        # Remap TabPrev to PgUp.
xmodmap -e 'keycode 167 = Next End XF86Forward'       # Remap TabNext to PgDn.
xmodmap -e 'keycode 151 = Control_L'    # Remap FN to be Ctrl.
xmodmap -e 'keycode  37 = XF86WakeUp'   # Remap Ctrl to be FN.
xmodmap -e 'keycode  94 = Shift_L'      # Remap stupid left |\*& to be Shift too.
```

However it's not exactly what I need as it maps Shift + Tab* to Home, which prevents me using the `Shift` + `Home'` combo (to select text) and only works in some applications (e.g. doesn't work in Firefox to go to the top).

So - how should I map it?

---

*Update:* I used `setkeycodes` and found these scancodes:

```
                 Press            Release
TabLeft  - 158   ^[[5~0xe0 0x6a   0xe0 0xea 
TabRight - 159   ^[[6~0xe0 0x69   0xe0 0xe9
PgUp:            0xe0 0x49        0xe0 0xc9 
PgDn:            0xe0 0x51        0xe0 0xd1 

Ctrl:            0x1d             0x9d 
FN:              0xe0 0x63        0xe0 0xe3
```

---

*Update:* I also found that `dumpkeys` shows interesting info.
Like, string aliases for some keys; e.g., the `^[[5~` shown by `showkey -s` is defined there.

---

*Update:*  I've tried `setkeycodes`:

```
sudo setkeycodes 0xE063  29  ##  Fn   to Ctrl
sudo setkeycodes 0x1d   143  ##  Ctrl to Fn
sudo setkeycodes 0x56    42  ##  |\*& to Shift
```

`showkeys` -k shows the right keycodes coming, but still they don't work so - e.g. `Ctrl+T` doesn't open a tab in FF etc.
After reverting the changes, everything works as before.

```
sudo setkeycodes 0xE063 143  ##  Fn   to Ctrl
sudo setkeycodes 0x1d    29  ##  Ctrl to Fn
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Came across this post looking for the status of the issue that key codes > 128 could not be mapped as modifier key. Last time I checked this was my reason for not being able to swap fn/ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd> keys in ThinkPad is possible in BIOS:
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht074187-how-to-swap-the-fn-function-and-ctrl-control-keyboard-keys-in-bios

For what I can tell this is the only working way as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> has some sort of special meaning and is impossible to be swapped on OS level.